# NextJS how to make pexels api pagination work

Tags: api, next.js

I am using NextJS to create a photo gallery with pexels api and want to add pagination to the project, but i didn't understand very well the documentation about pagination, so i dont know what i have to do to make this work.

What i want is to have a buttom at the bottom of the gallery saying "show more" and when i click it will show more photos.

this is my code:

[image: Photo of the code]

Comment: Please use code snippets, do not use images for code.

Comment: Ok i'll update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create two react states.

```
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [perPage, setPerpage] = useState(10);
```

Here we are facing 10 images per page, if you want you can change how many images you want per page.

Then just convert your URL like the following.

```
  const url = `https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?page=${page}&per_page=${perPage}`
  const data = await fetch(url)
```

Do that inside that useEffect hook. Now everything you want to load more just increment the perPage state. And if you want to get a new page and new image, then change the page state.